# Mudar o conteudo da Modal Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tenho uma Grid com o botão editar quando clico nela ela acessa o Controller e traz os dados de um determinado usuario em um Modal.

Mas ela está trazendo apenas do primeiro usuario que eu clico.

Segue o código:

**Link da Grid**

```
<a href=".../show/{{$valor->id}}" data-target="#editModal" data-toggle="modal">Editar</a></td>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/show/{id}', '...\EscolaController@show');
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{


    $escola = $this->escola->find($id);


    return view('....editEscolas', compact('escola'));
}
```

Comment: Você está fazendo via **ajax** ? Esta dando algum erro ?

Comment: Não estou usando ajax achei que com o Laravel diretamente pelo Controller dava certo

Comment: Então como você está ativando o sem refresh ? Poderia postar o código completo ?

Comment: Nao seria sem o refresh quando clica no link da grid dou um get na Route e acesso o Controller **show($id)** e ele retorna para view **editEscolas** que seria o Modal

Comment: Vou testar um momento.

Comment: Todos os usuários que você clica para editar carregam os mesmos dados no modal, é isso? Como se tivesse clicando sempre no mesmo usuário?

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de fazer um exemplo bem simplista e funcionou aqui.
Veja se te ajuda:

**Route**

```
Route::get('see/{id}', 'Adm\UsuarioController@show');
```

**Controller**

```
$data['usuario'] = User::find($id);
```

**Botão de solicitação**

```
@foreach($usuarios as $key => $value) <!-- Aqui eu tenho todos os meus usuários -->
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-block" href='{{url("see/$value->id")}}'>
    See
</a>
@endforeach
```

**Apresentação do modal**

```
@if(isset($usuario))
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{$usuario->name}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            {{$usuario->email}}
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

Veja que o principal é você saber se existe algum usuário naquela rota.
Eu pergunto se esta setado algum usuário, caso positivo eu mostro meu modal com as informações.

Espero ter ajudado.