# Passar dados do Controller para um modal na view Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, modal

Estou tentando passar dados de um Controller para um Modal na view.

Na view  eu tenho esse código que popula um datatable assim que a página e carregada:

```
....
@foreach($exames as $exame)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$exame->registro}}</td>
                        <td>{{$exame->nome}}</td>
                        <td>{{$exame->motivo}}</td>
                        <td>{{$exame->telefone.' '.$exame->celular.' '.$exame->tel_recado}}</td>
                        <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($exame->data)->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="{{url('/info_exame',$exame->id)}}">Visualizar</a>
                            <!--<button type="button" class=" btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default-{{$exame->id}}">Visualizar</button>-->
                            <a href="{{url('/edita_exames', $exame->id)}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Editar</a>                               
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-apaga-{{$exame->id}}">Apagar</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
....
```

Para popular esse datatable eu utilizao essa Rota:

```
Route::get('/agenda_exames', 'AgendaExamesController@index')->name('agenda_exames');
```

Com esse Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $exames = Tab_exames::all();

    return view('agendaexames', compact('exames'));
}
```

Eu estava posicionando o Modal dentro do @foreach após a tabela, só que no meu entendimento não é uma maneira correta de se utilizar já que se o banco possuir milhares de registros, fico imaginando o tamanho que será esse arquivo da view.

Pois bem, procurando aqui no stack eu encontrei esse exemplo:

[Mudar o conteudo da Modal Laravel 5.1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143895/mudar-o-conteudo-da-modal-laravel-5-1)

Segui o exemplo criando essa Rota:

```
Route::get('/info_exame/{id}', 'AgendaExamesController@show');
```

Com esse Controller

```
public function show($id){

    $info_exame = Tab_exames::findOrFail($id);
    return view('agendaexames', compact('info_exame'));        
}
```

Têm umas diferenças entre o meu código e o código do exemplo, mas acho que isso não seria problema.

Meu Modal está dessa forma

```
@if(isset($info_exame->id))
<!--Modal Mostra Dados Exame-->
<div class="modal modal-success fade" id="modal-default" tabIndex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Informações sobre o agendamento do exame</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">                                            
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                    <label>Data do exame</label>
                    <p><b>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($info_exame->data)->format('d-m-Y') }}</b></p></p>
                </div>                                                                                  
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">                                            
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span>
                    <label>Nº Registro</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->registro}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span>
                    <label>Nome</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->nome}}</p>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span class="fa fa-wheelchair"></span>
                    <label>Deficiência</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->deficiencia}}</p>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="row">                                             
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span>
                    <label>Motivo</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->motivo}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                    <label>Telefone</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->telefone}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                    <label>Celular</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->celular}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                    <label>Recado</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->tel_recado}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                    <label>Nome do contato</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->nome_contato}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>
                    <label>Observações</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->observacoes}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>

            <div class="row"> 

                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <span class="fa fa-user-circle"></span>
                    <label>Cadastrado por</label>
                    <p>{{$info_exame->operador}}</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <span class="fa fa fa-calendar"></span>
                    <label>Gravado em</label>
                    <p>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($info_exame->created_at)->format('d-m-Y - H:i:s') }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <span class="fa fa fa-calendar"></span>
                    <label>Atualizado em</label>
                    <p>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($info_exame->update_at)->format('d-m-Y - H:i:s') }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>                                    
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#modal-default').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Ao clicar no botão da tabela eu tenho esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode estar errado?
Existe outra forma mais correta e objetiva de passar os dados do controller para um modal?

Comment: Isso acontece pq ele tá procurando a variável $exames, mas não acha pq tu não tá passando ela no método show. Deixa teu foreach dentro desse if: @if(isset($exames))

Comment: @DiegoVieira a variável $exames vêm de outra função dentro do controller e é utilizada para popular a tabela, inclusive o botão "Visualizar" que pega o id para passar pro controller show. Para popular o modal estou usando outra função no controller.

Comment: Sim, mas o" show" redireciona para o mesmo arquivo que o "index", correto?

Comment: Isso, exatamente isso.

Comment: Quando tu chama o método show, ele redireciona novamente para essa página, então ele "perde" a variável exames. Tenta colocar o foreach dentro do if que eu falei pra ver se vai abrir o modal.

Comment: Nesse caso vai ficar praticamente da mesma forma que eu estava utilizando antes, ou seja, meu modal estava dentro do foreach. Pelo que eu entendi então o Laravel não permite que sejam utilizadas mais de uma função dentro de um mesmo controller que tem rotas para a mesma view?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72366/discussion-between-diego-vieira-and-henqsan).

Comment: @DiegoVieira consegui resolver com javascript mesmo. Primeiro eu uso o recurso do "data" do modal no botão, exemplo: data-nome. Depois eu uso o javascript para pegar as informações e passar para o modal: `$(document).on('click', '.info-exame', function() { 
$('#nome').text($(this).data('nome')); 
$('#modal-default').modal('show'); 
});`